# Trying to get Session value in Global.asax, but it is NULL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, global-asax

I have a session which contains a `List(of String)` which I create on `Main.aspx`. In my `Global.asax` I execute the following code to retrieve the `Session` value after a `Timer` is fired.

```
  Private Sub Application_AcquireRequestState(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session IsNot Nothing Then
            If Session("Products") IsNot Nothing Then
                Response.Write(Session("Products").ToString())
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

However, `Session("Products")` returns Null and the `Sub` is exited. I wonder if `End Sub` in `Main.aspx` releases the `Session` and therefore whenever the `Timer` fires, the `Session` is empty. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi there, perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195791/context-session-object-is-null-in-application-acquirerequeststate) question can help?

Answer (score 0):

In your Main.vb code behind, be sure to inherit the  `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState` interface in addition to whatever is being inherited.

Something like this should work:

```
Public Class Main 
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page, System.Web.SessionState.IRequireSessionState
' Your application code
End Class
```

This is strange behavior though as ASP.NET webpages should already handle session data. Usually, you inherit `IRequireSessionState` on generic handlers (.ashx) since they don't support session data by default.

Comment: Isn't that I can only call `inherits` once in a class? Because I already have `Inherits System.Web.UI.Page` I cannot add `Inherits System.Web.SessionState.IRequireSessionState`. even if I removed the first inherit and added the inherit Session, it shows an error `Classes inherit only from other Classes`.

Comment: You would change your inherits statement to this `Inherits System.Web.UI.Page, System.Web.SessionState.IRequireSessionState`. I think that `System.Web.UI.Page` already inherits `IRequireSessionState` though. Note that VB.NET does not support multiple class inheritance, but you can inherit multiple interfaces.